# Determining if subset S = [a b c] where a, b, c are ≥ 0 is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the described set is a subspace. Assume a, b, and c are real numbers.
The subset of R3 consisting of vectors of the form [a b c]
, where a ≥ 0, b ≥ 0, and c ≥ 0.

Here is my reasoning so far.

A subset S is a subspace if all of the following are true:
a) If it contains 0. In this case a = b = c = 0 creates a 0 vector so it could be a subspace.
b) When any vector in S is closed under addition. I said because a, b, c are all ≥ 0, u + v in S must be still be ≥ 0. Therefore it's closed under addition.
c) If it's closed under multiplication. I said it's not closed under multiplication because you can multiply a negative scalar (??)

Because condition c is not met, I think it's ultimately not a subspace. I would like to confirm my answer before submitting it.

Also, I'm really struggling with this topic and I have a test coming up so any tips and suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the set is not a subspace because it is not closed under multiplication. I would add a clarifying example, so I would say that $[1,1,1]$ is in $S$, but $(-1)\cdot [1,1,1]$ is not.

Also, one more correction: a set is a subset if it is closed under addition and multiplication. You do not need to check if $0$ is in the set, as $0$ is in *any* set that is closed under multiplication.

Comment: The assertion "$0$ is in any set that is closed under multiplication" is not quite right. It is in any *non-empty* set that is closed under multiplication. The emptyset is usually not considered as a subspace  and this part of the defintiion of subspace is there to exclude it. (One could also impose non-emptyness in the definition and check for it directly. But one of the two should be done, if one wishes to be precise.)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and as far as further suggestions, your process is a good one too - there's not much to do other than to just check through the list of criteria.